# Elasticsearch: Nested mapping throws error on search

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

The snapshots below are self-explanatory but here's what I am trying to do. I have a double nested filed ***stream.tagging.tag*** and it's I recreated my index with new mappings. But when I do a search, ES fails to find path for inner nested field.

```
nishant-osx:~ nishagar$ curl GET 'localhost:9200/stream_rules/_mappings?pretty'
{
  "stream_rules": {
    "mappings": {
      "stream_rule": {
        "properties": {
          "stream": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "tagging": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "displayName": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "tag": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "store": true
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

nishant-osx:~ nishagar$ CURL 'localhost:9200/stream_rules/_search' -d '{
>     "query": {
>         "nested" : {
>             "path" : "stream",
>             "query" : {
>                 "nested": {
>                     "path": "tagging",
>                     "query": {
>                         "bool" : {
>                         "must" : { "match" : {"stream.tagging.tag" : "product"} }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }'
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[Xh51BRC6SXekokw5jD5IzQ][stream_rules][0]: SearchParseException[[stream_rules][0]...
QueryParsingException[[stream_rules] [nested] failed to find nested object under path [tagging]]; }]","status":400}
```

Answer (score 0):

The nested path in the query is incorrect.

```
{
 "query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "stream",
        "query": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "stream.tagging",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "match": {
                                "stream.tagging.tag": "product"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```